# Wireless on my Dell Latitude E5320 doesn't work on Ubuntu but works on Linux Mint. What can I do to make it work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

I have dualboot Ubuntu 12.10 & Linux Mint 14, both are clean install & updated with the latest. My wireless works flawlessly on Linux Mint but it's very unreliable on Ubuntu: every 15~20 minutes, the wireless icon still shows "connected" status but I can't go to any website. Pinging URL & IP both result in no network activities. Reboot fix the problem but it would happen again within 15~20 minutes.

I really like Unity. Any idea to help make Ubuntu works for me? Or what's the different in wireless module between Linx Mint & Ubuntu? Anyway I can bring it from Linux Mint to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find differences between the two system setups

1. Determine which hardware is used (e.g. lspci)
2. Therefore which module in which version is used (lsmod, modinfo)
3. Check network connectivity settings (network-manager, ifconfig / iwconfig)

If there are e.g. different version of the module, you can try an update.

Comment: Hey there, they are on the same laptop so there can't be any hardware difference,but I'll check the rest.

Comment: that's for sure, but you should determine the hardware anyway, also the get a more specific answer here or on other websites.

Comment: @domi27 OP stated that both systems were fully up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dmesg | grep firmware` to check which firmware is missing. Install them from packages or find proper firmware elsewhere. Sometime you need different version than provided in repository.

Keep in mind that you don't have installed conflicting network related applications like network-manager, wicd and connection-manager.